# Liking - Aggregating One Number For All Pages

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-like

I have Facebook Likes buttons on every page of my website. I want it so that when a user Likes, there will be a Like pointing to the current page they are on. But the number will reflect how many Likes for the entire page. I am wondering if this is possible?

From my understanding, the number of Likes is associated with the link the user is liking. Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook like buttons are linked to a URL - either that of your website home:

```
www.example.com
```

OR separately a single page

```
www.example.com/post-about-example
```

When you create the like button you decide what the like is against - essentially if you are selecting the home page - it is still only liking a single page, but its just the main page you want the facebook profile to link to. You need to have each button liking EITHER your home OR your individual page - one button cannot do both.

On a side note - from an SEO standpoint, it is better if your likes are associated with your home page as this should link to your most important pages first - reaping the best SEO benefit for the more important pages - whilst also directing users to what is set up as a landing page.

If your site is one which relies on multiple posts, say a blog. It may be better to go down the path whereby each post url has its own facebook like button FOR THAT URL. This way each post gets more exposure.

I hope that answers your question.